# Problems downloading Ubunu 20.04 from Ubuntu.com

Tags: 22.04, iso

5 (five!) times I have tried to download Ubuntu 22.04 for desktop and I could never make
It always stop before finishing. Does anybody know anything about these problems_

Thank you, Monica

Comment: Please use the torrent download option to prevent download interrupts.

Comment: Unable to duplicate: Both 20.04 and 22.04 download fully and rapidly to my desktop. Are you perhaps on an unreliable, throttled, or proxied connection?

Answer (score 0):

Download interruptions can occur for various reasons, such as a slow or unstable internet connection, server issues, or browser problems. I have downloaded the Ubuntu from their website and never faced such an issue. Follow some of these steps before trying:

- Check Your **Internet Connection is stable**. You can even try
  restarting your modem or router.
- Consider using a **Download Manager** or a browser extension that can
  resume interrupted downloads. These tools can help if your downloads
  are frequently interrupted.
- Sometimes, download issues can be caused by high server loads or
  server problems. Try **downloading Ubuntu from a different mirror**.
  You can select a different mirror on the Ubuntu download page.
- If you are downloading Ubuntu through a web browser, **clearing your
  browser's cache and cookies** can sometimes resolve download issues.
- Try using a **different browser** to see if the issue persists.
- Ubuntu is often available for **download via torrent**. Using a
  torrent clients can be more resilient to interruptions.

I hope these steps will fix your problem.